# Webclient UploadValues encoding

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, webclient

Im making a `POST` in a URL and getting the response as a string like this:

```
var responseBytes = client.UploadValues("www.example.com", requestData.Body);
var html = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
html = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(html);
```

Ive created a WebClient child to accept cookies so i made a this class:

```
 public class CookieWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; }

    public CookieWebClient()
    {
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    }

    public CookieWebClient(CookieContainer cookieContainer)
    {
        CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        if (request == null) return base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
        return request;
    }
}
```

As you can see i set the encode in the constructor. But when i get the `html` property some characters are coming like: `� necess�rio` and it should be `É necessário`.

Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: Well what encoding is the server actually using? Have you looked at the bytes being returned?

Comment: `var html = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);` ?

Comment: @RubensFarias Make a answer with it and ill accept as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using "Latin 1" characters (portuguese, maybe?), so you should go with:

```
var html = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
                   .GetString  (responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
```